# meaning the adjective "messed up" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course A&P](https://youtu.be/rd2cf5hValM). It is at 2 minute and 6 second. Here it goes:

> Specifically, they go around wearing parts of the organisms they have killed so others can see them. Sounds a little bit **messed up**, but we are talking life and death here.

I have checked what the adjective means, and have checked what the phrasal verb *mess up* means, but still have a hard time understanding what it means there.

Comment: I know it's not really appropriate, but I find that the best way to explain it is by saying it's a milder, perhaps euphemistic way of saying [*f\*\*\*ed up*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=That%27s%20fucked%20up). Of course, here *messed up* isn't a standalone phrase as in that Urban Dictionary entry, but still. The third definition [here](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=messed+up) is also pertinent.

Comment: messed up (slang) = crazy, pathological, mentally disturbed or traumatized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Messed up" can be the past tense of "mess up", but it is also slang. The [definition of messed up in the Online Slang dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/messed-up) lists several variations (the example sentences are ones I came up with because the examples from the site have been redacted):

> 1. severely under the influence of alcohol or drugs.
>      *We got so messed up on St. Patrick's day that we couldn't go in to work the next day.*
> 2. disturbed, confused, etc.
>      *She wears raw bacon as jewelry - it's really messed up!*
> 3. unfortunate.
>      *It's messed up that you didn't get a chance to audition because you were 5 minutes late.*

In this sense (organisms wearing parts of other organisms), I think the "that's really weird/crazy" sense fits best.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the meanings of the phrasal verb *to mess up* copied from [Longman's dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mess-up):

> **mess up (phrasal verb) (informal)**
>
> **1 mess something ↔ up**
>
> to spoil or ruin something, especially something important or something that has been carefully planned
>
> It took me ages to get this right – I don’t want some idiot to mess it up.
>   She felt she’d messed up her whole life.
>
> **2 mess something ↔ up**
>
> to make something dirty or untidy
>
> Who messed up the kitchen?
>
> **3 mess something ↔ up**
>
> to make a mistake and do something badly:
>
> I think I messed up on the last question.
>
> It doesn’t matter if you mess it up, you can always try again.
>
> **4 mess somebody ↔ up**
>
> to make someone have emotional or mental problems
>
> I messed up my kids.
>
> **5 mess somebody ↔ up** (American English) (informal)
>
> to hurt someone especially by hitting them

The adjective is formed on basis of these meanings, one of them is to apply for the context.